# How can I run a youtube video on my page at a certain time every day, even if I'm not on the page?

Tags: youtube-api

I would like that on my home page will be a screen of a youtube video, that runs every day between 10am 2 11am. The video length is 1 hour exacly. I know how to embed the video but it's not enough 4 my request. I want it to play even if I'm not on the website.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "play?" Do you mean that you want to open a browser to the appropriate site and play the video?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

The first is to use some kind of scheduled task that opens a browser to the appropriate page. You can find more information about the Windows Task Scheduler [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx).

Some people will also use a Windows Service and a timer to do something similar to the above, but I don't recommend that because the service will "hang around" in memory even when it's not actually needed - the Task Scheduler is a better solution because you can run an appropriate script or executable only when it's actually needed.

You could also use Selenium. See how to schedule something daily in Selenium [here](https://www.quora.com/How-to-schedule-a-daily-execution-of-selenium-ide-recordings-grouped-in-a-test-suit-so-that-every-morning-i-can-get-details-of-results-or-failures).